# Jquery Datatable not working i am a beginner

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am starting out on Asp.net MVC using Mosh Complete MVC Course on Udemy as a learning guide..Currently trying to implement the default JQuery Datatable with not configuration..Everything works fine until this line is added

```
$("#customers").DataTable();
```

I have tried updating bootstrap and jquery but still no luck.
At the console i get no error message..but it just does not work. Please help a newbie. Thanks.

Comment: Did you install table jquery plugin ?

Comment: what is the error message you are getting (check your console) ?

Comment: I'm sorry...I'm new to this..been trying to debug my app and found this error at the console.. jQuery.Deferred exception: cannot read property 'mData' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property'mData'of type undefined...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377637/datatables-cannot-read-property-mdata-of-undefined

Comment: Try this video https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/videos/jquery/how-do-i-make-ajax-calls-using-jquery

Comment: sounds like your includes are missing or out of order.  Is your code inside a $(document).ready?

Answer (score 0):

1st add jquery-1.12.4.js before using

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
```

then use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

DataTables requires a well-formed table. It must contain  and  tags, otherwise it throws this error. Also, make sure that you have the same amount of table data in your project.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, to solve it make sure your table is organized properly. The heading should be wrapped in a thead and the body in tbody and also the title rows amount should be the same as the body row amount. example of a table that will work with datatables

```
<table id="sample-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>title-1</th>
        <th>title-2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>data-1</td>
        <td>data-2</td>
        <td>data-3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to know that DataTables needs that your table is in a well formatted. Check if there is a condition that you will control the appearance of a column or not.
You need to make the  tag outside the if condition. you will check the other format problem that will cause that your table is not well formatted.
[As you see here in this picture the  tag outside the if condition.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNCRa.png)