# DataTables throwing error when colspan in table header cell

Tags: jquery, html-table, datatables

I'm getting the following error when using a colspan in my th tag.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
```

Normally this error occurs when the number of table cells is not equal in every row, but this is not the case. Here is my code:

```
<table id="foo">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="5">asdf</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $('#foo').DataTable();
</script>
```

Here is an example in codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EQOVMe?editors=1111

Using jquery 1.12.3 and Data Tables 1.10.16

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a known issue, as per answer and conversation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377637/datatables-cannot-read-property-mdata-of-undefined

Comment: Hmm, not sure why it's not working when according to this `rowspan` and `colspan` are fully supported in headers. https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation [here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html), Datatables supports `colspan` and `rowspan` in the headers, but with this caveat.

> Each column must have one TH cell which is unique to it for the listeners to be added.

I figured out a hacky workaround and I don't know if it's the best solution, but it does provide a working solution nonetheless.

Create two header rows and use the first header row with the `colspan` attribute and the second header row with all the individual columns.  Then apply css `display: none` to hide the row.  This will allow the datatable to initialize without erroring.  However, I'm not sure if it might cause any side effects with other functionality.

**UPDATE**

Initially I applied `display: none` using css but this solution didn't draw the table using the full width of the container.  So I modified this to apply the style in code after the table was initialized and drawn.  This allows it to display in the full container width.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#foo').DataTable();
  $("tr.hideme").css({"display" : "none"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="foo">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5">asdf</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hideme">
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice one, great answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use two tr inside thead of the table. It is not different than normally using colspan and rowspan in table. You can see the [jsfiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/f19zxtfm/4/)

```
<table width="100%" id="example">
  <thead style="background:#C0C0C0;">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5">first headline</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="padding-left: 15px;"> Id </th>
      <th> Product Name </th>
      <th> Total Events </th>
      <th> Total Revenue </th>
      <th> Rental Time </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>4804</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>9608</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```