# Datatables with colspan throwing error - cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')

Tags: javascript

I am using `datatables.net` library and in the docs there is an example of using `colspan` for headers. But it is throwing an error and I can't seem to find what the issue is

Docs: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
    at _fnCalculateColumnWidths (jquery.dataTables.js:3965:20)
    at _fnInitialise (jquery.dataTables.js:3095:4)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:6301:5)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.9.1.js:648:23)
    at init.each (jquery-1.9.1.js:270:17)
    at init.DataTable [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.js:5838:8)
    at init.$.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.js:14206:18)
    at ?editor_console=true:132:25
```

HTML code:

```
<table id="table" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th colspan="2" class="center">Job & Salary</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript code:

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable();
```

Here is also a JSFiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/vf5sk76L/

Comment: From the page you linked: "_Each column must have one TH cell which is unique to it for the listeners to be added._"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DataTables throwing error when colspan in table header cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998297/datatables-throwing-error-when-colspan-in-table-header-cell)