# Datatable Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, datatable, html-table

I'm using **datatable** to form a table by an array in Javascript:

```
<table class="table display" id='contest__table' style="width:100%">
</table>

var dataSet = [
        [ "player1", "1", "0", "upgrade level "],
        [ "player1", "2", "0", "upgrade level "],
        [ "player1", "3", "0", "upgrade level "],
        [ "player1", "4", "0", "upgrade level "],
        [ "player1", "5", "0", "upgrade level "],
        [ "player1", "6", "0", "upgrade level "],
        [ "player1", "7", "0", "upgrade level "],
        [ "player1", "8", "0", "upgrade level "],
        [ "player1", "9", "0", "upgrade level "],
        [ "player1", "10", "0", "upgrade level "]
    ];

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#contest__table').DataTable( {
               data: dataSet,
                    columns: [
                       { title: "Player" },
                       { title: "column1" },
                       { title: "column2" },
                       { title: "column3" }
                     ]
        } );
    } );
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PejpGW)

The weird thing is that it works fine in codepen but it does not work in my website.

It always returns "Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined". Even though I'm using the exact same code & libraries. My table does not have anything inside table tag same as my codepen.

Please give me advice if you have experienced this.

Comment: you have same dataSet in your site also?

Comment: @Nirali Yes, everything is the same from the HTML to the js & the libraries. I really have no idea.

Comment: @puccagaru There is already an issue regarding the same. Please look into the link below.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377637/datatables-cannot-read-property-mdata-of-undefined#25965255

Comment: @sridhar reddy Thanks