# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined Angular 6

Tags: angular, datatable

I Used data tables in my normal table. I only used `datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"`:

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="table table-default table-sm table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Pay Units</th>
        <th>IsActive</th>
        <th></th>
        <th><i class="fa fa-rotate-right" (click)="Refresh()"></i></th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let payunit of PayUnits">
        <td>{{payunit.Name}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="payunit.IsActive"></td>
        <td><i (click)="setUpDate(payunit)" class="fa fa-edit editbtn"></i></a></td>
        <td><i (click)="delete(payunit.ID)" class="fa fa-close reject"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

but it gives error 
**Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined** how to solve this error:  [image: error in chrome developer tool]

Comment: post your table code, jquery dataTables requires a well formed table. It must contain <thead> and <tbody> tags.

Comment: can you post some your code and what you try to solve this and not working if there's any, just to clarify your problem ... add your code to your post

Comment: I not added <thead>  in my table. when i added as mentioned first comment, it working. thank you

Comment: notice that you should first search your question and error if you didn't get right answer then ask it here, your question is available at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377637/datatables-cannot-read-property-mdata-of-undefined

Comment: ok i got it , thanks  fateme fazli

Answer (score 1):

Column miss match between angular databind and html view.